# BigQuery size of Capacitor format much bigger than in Hadoop (ORC)

Tags: hadoop, google-bigquery

During my first tests with BigQuery, I've observed that the size of a table imported in BigQuery is much bigger than its original representation in Hadoop.

Here are the numbers that I get:

- ORC original Hadoop table: 2GB
- Avro compressed representation to load the data into BigQuery: 6.4 GB
- (test: Avro uncompressed: 45.8 GB)
- size in BigQuery (Capacitor format): 47.1 GB

This table has 11 million rows, with 366 columns (most of them being "strings").

Is it a normal behavior from BigQuery? I thought that Capacitor optimized the data in a very efficient way.

Is there any way to see the internal structures of my data in BigQuery to understand what is going wrong and what causes such amount of space being generated?

Comment: See here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739171/is-it-possible-to-load-avro-files-with-snappy-compression-into-bigquery

Comment: Actually, I don't face the problem mentioned in that thread, since loading into BigQuery works fine for me (I use the Deflate codec for my Avro files).

What seems strange to me is that the space used by BigQuery for this data is 23 times more than the space used by ORC. If capacitor has a columnar representation, and is also able to reorder the rows in order to improve encoding/compression (see https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/04/inside-capacitor-bigquerys-next-generation-columnar-storage-format), then I would expect the space used in BigQuery to be at least as small as in ORC.

Comment: BigQuery displays the uncompressed sizes for tables, not the compressed sizes

Comment: @ElliottBrossard - does that mean BigQuery charges for querying the uncompressed data rather than compressed? (it's the other way around in e.g. AWS Athena)

Comment: Yes: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#data